# CouchDB _changes sequence limitation

Tags: couchdb

What will happen if the changes sequence number reaches maximum value of sequence number. Will you get the last sequence as zero in _changes response json. If you get last sequence as zero then are we refetching the older changes or newer ones.

How does a rolling happens in this case. We are using _changes for a very critical processing chain and want to know your inputs.

Comment: You'll get a better response to this question in either the #couchdb IRC channel, or on the mailing list, details and links here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/#Community

Comment: @Arun George have you found an answer? I would like to know how it works as well.